# MySQL calling in Username to show instead of ID?

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have a users table, books table and authors table. An author can have many books, while a user can also have many books. (This is how my DB is currently setup). As I'm pretty new to So far my setup is like `bookview.php?book_id=23` from accessing authors page, then seeing all books for the author. The single book's details are all displayed on this new page...I can get the output to display the user ID associated with the book, but not the user name, and this also applies for the author's name, I can the author ID to display, but not the name, so somewhere in the query below I am not calling in the correct values:

```
SELECT users.user_id, 
       authors.author_id, 
       books.book_id, 
       books.bookname, 
       books.bookprice, 
       books.bookplot 
  FROM books 
INNER JOIN authors on books.book_id = authors.book_id 
INNER JOIN users ON books.book_id = users.user_id 
 WHERE books.book_id=" . $book_id;
```

Could someone help me correct this so I can display the author name and user name both associated with the book! Thanks for the help :)

Comment: It looks like you simply forgot to include those columns in your select statement. We could easily add them for you but you'll have to tell us how the tables look like first :)

Comment: Wow, am I an idiot or not!!! Oh dear sorry about this haha, I spent an hour trying to do this aswell! I knew I was close :)

Comment: You can delete the question - there's no reputation penalty.  The link is to the left of your username, under the tags.

Answer (score 1):

I think the right join conditions would be something like (changes bolded)

`SELECT users.user_id,

       **users.user_name,**

       authors.author_id,

       **authors.author_name,**

       books.book_id,

       books.bookname,

       books.bookprice,

       books.bookplot

  FROM books

INNER JOIN authors on books.**author_id** = authors.**author_id**

INNER JOIN users ON books.**user_id** = users.user_id

 WHERE books.book_id=" . $book_id;`

Or you can use the less verbose syntax for simple inner joins.

`SELECT users.user_id,

       users.user_name,

       authors.author_id,

       authors.author_name,

       books.book_id,

       books.bookname,

       books.bookprice,

       books.bookplot

  FROM books, authors, users

       where books.author_id = authors.author_id

       and books.user_id = users.user_id

       and books.book_id=" . $book_id`

Answer (score 0):

It would help if I added the name fields into the select query :D

Answer (score 0):

These two joins together:

```
INNER JOIN authors on books.book_id = authors.book_id 
INNER JOIN users ON books.book_id = users.user_id
```

also imply `authors.book_id = users.user_id` which, on the face of it, makes no sense.  Surely the code you've posted is not the code you're actually using...?